# ImageButton. How to have the standard "glow" efect when pressed

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton with a transparent image in it. I changed the background color of the ImageButton.

When an ImageButton that has the default color is pressed the button shows that it has been pressed by "glowing" for a very short time. But when the background color is changed the "glow" effect doesn't show. The different behavior doesn't have to do with the image, because the "glow" effect is shown when the button has the standard "grayish" color.

How could I have the "glow" effect in a colored Imagebutton?

P.S. I am aware of how to change the color of the ImageButton on a click event. But I want to have the same effect with the default grey-colored ImageButton.
The same thing (glowing not shows) happen also with the Button object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library

[RippleView](https://github.com/siriscac/RippleView)

[image]

Comment: I would rather have the standard behavior back. Do you know why it goes away then one changes the background color?

Comment: When you change the background color the default style will no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) to define your button's `pressed` color.

You should review the documentation I linked above for details. Here's a quick example from the doc, which covers the basics:

> XML file saved at res/color/button_text.xml:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <item android:state_pressed="true"
>           android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
>     <item android:state_focused="true"
>           android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
>     <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
> </selector>
> ```
>
> This layout XML will apply the color list to a View:
>
> ```
> <Button
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="@string/button_text"
>     android:textColor="@color/button_text" />
> ```

In your case, you'll want to set `android:background` to point to your new XML resource, instead of `android:textColor`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The android have the glow effect as a transparent background resource, so I solved the problem by putting a colored view behind the button and setting the button background to the transparent glow effect.

For example in my xml like:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/custom_color"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and in my onCreate:

```
TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true);
Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
mButton.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
```

Its working only, if you have just one buttons in your `LinearLayout`, if you want to put there something else you can use a view inside a `RelativeLayout` with the same parameters as your button.

Tell me if you have any other questions!